# Seaborn: How to increase the font size of the labels on the axes?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

Here's how I plot the heat map:

```
sns.heatmap(table, annot=True, fmt='g', annot_kws={'size':24})
```

The thing is, `size` set only the font size of the numbers inside the heatmap. Which parameter I should use in `annot_kws` to set the font size of the labels on the axes?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot change those directly in the call to `heatmap`, but you can instruct matplotlib to change the font size either [in `plt.rcParams` directly](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html), or using a [context manager](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#temporary-styling):

```
uniform_data = np.random.rand(10, 12)
plt.figure()
with plt.style.context({'axes.labelsize':24,
                        'xtick.labelsize':8,
                        'ytick.labelsize':16}):
    ax = sns.heatmap(uniform_data, annot=True, fmt='.1f', annot_kws={'size':6})
    ax.set_xlabel('x label')
```

[image]